# Three.js as background of website possible?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, background, three.js, webgl

I've been looking at using three.js for a fun experiment on a site. I would like to use a current experiment (for which I already have the code for) and use it as a background for my site.

Anybody know how to do this?

I saw it done here: http://janjorissen.be/

Three JS API: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: roflmao! Don't worry, it's for a proof of concept experiment for my profile, not for actual use. I know better than that. Calm down.

Comment: Okay, good to know. :-) There are people out there, who'd do that, so I just wondered. I have no idea with what kind of strange diseases they are obsessed with. But you're right - why should't you experiment with it. Sorry for suspecting you to be one of those. :P

Comment: hehe! :-) No worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usually i use iframe for that. Thus you dont have conflict with the base page.

```
<style>
iframe {
    z-index : -9999;
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    left    : 0;
    width   : 100%;
    height  : 100%;
    margin  : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
</style>
<iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
```

an example of it
https://github.com/jeromeetienne/www.jetienne.com/blob/master/index-webgl.html#L128 for the source
http://jetienne.com/index-webgl.html for the living code

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try my experiment and post back my sample this weekend. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to add little scrollbars with chrome. I don't know why but I also see it in the working example and it doesn't look very neat. I think it is better to just put it in a container.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to add yet another answer. I'd use

```
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

Here's why:

Many people use `canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }` but that arguably doesn't make a lot of sense. You don't want the canvas to be 100% of the body. You want it to 100% of the screen/window. That's what `canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }` does. It's 100% of the viewport width and viewport height.

This means you don't need to set the body to height: 100% which also would not make sense, especially if the page is taller than the window/screen

`display: block;` fixes some issues with scrollbars on certain browsers. Some pages use `html, body { overflow: none; }` but again that doesn't make sense if your page ends up needing to be taller than the screen/window.

`position: fixed;` makes the canvas position relative to the top of window so it won't scroll with the page. If you use `position: absolute` then the canvas will scroll off the top if the page is taller than the screen/window. For example [this page](https://twgljs.org).

`top: 0; left 0;` puts it at the top left. Without that it would default to it's default position which is inside the body's margins. Often this is solved by setting `body { margin: 0; }` but generally that means you end up needing some other container to add a margin back in otherwise your normal content gets positioned at the edge of the window.

`z-index: -9999;` is there to try to force it further back than anything else just in case the page itself is using some negative values for `z-index`

Here's an example as a snippet

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
renderer.setClearColor(0xF0F0F0);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
  color: 0x00ff00, 
  wireframe: true,
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 1;

function resize() {
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (width != canvas.width || height != canvas.height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    resize();
    cube.rotation.x = time;
    cube.rotation.y = time * 0.31;
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.min.js"></script>

<canvas></canvas>
<div>
  some content that is in front of the canvas
</div>
```

And [here's an example outside SO](https://greggman.github.io/doodles/background-canvas.html) so you can view it easier full size.

[`iframe`s work as well](https://greggman.github.io/doodles/background-canvas-interactive-iframe.html)

Note that there's the issue that if your canvas animation is interactive the elements in front of the canvas will eat the mouse/touch events. There's no easy solution I know of for that. You can mark everything but that canvas/iframe as `pointer-events: none` and mark the canvas/iframe as `pointer-events: auto` but then you run into the issue that no text on your page can be selected and no links can be clicked. You could then say set `<a>` tags to have `pointer-events: auto` so links work but I'm sure there will be issues here and there depending on what info is on your page (trying to copy an email address, or a location address, etc...)

One note: most three.js examples are structured different (less flexible) by referencing `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` and putting the canvas inside a div with an `id="canvas"` for some reason.

Here's a snippet using that structure. There's several more lines of code, redundant calls to `renderer.setSize` and setting the camera aspect in 2 places (not very D.R.Y.) but as far as this Q&A is concerned the only difference is `#canvas` instead of `canvas` as the CSS to size the div instead of the canvas.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xF0F0F0);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
  color: 0x00ff00, 
  wireframe: true,
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 1;

function onResize() {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    cube.rotation.x = time;
    cube.rotation.y = time * 0.31;
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"></div>
<div>
  some content that is in front of the canvas
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an actual background, but a 100% width/height element that is displaying the animation, with the rest of the content "elevated" using `z-index` or similar above that fake background.

Comment: Awesome. That simple, huh? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Following the very basic example on threejs.org ([here](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene)), I only had to change the canvas style section to:

```
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

That moved the canvas to the background.